# Excel VBA Loop to Sum two consecutive cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to using VBA within Excel and have come stuck while trying to create a loop to sum two consecutive numbers and output that to a merged cell to the side. The data looks as below:

```
Number    -   Sum
  1       -   8 
  7       -    
  1       -   2 
  1       -
```

So I would like to loop throug the numbers in column 1 and add up the first 2 numbers (1 and 7 which would be cells A1 and A2) and return that value to the merged cell to the right of it which would be B1.

Below is what I have so far which does calculate correctly Cells A1 and A2 and put the value of 8 into Cell B1 but then just doesnt work at all. I have got a loop to work with calculating 2 values in seperate rows before but can't ge tmy head around how i can do that in this situation.

```
Sub Loop_Sum()
Set rng = Range("A1:A6")
For Each cell In rng
Cells(cell, 2) = Cells(cell, 1) + Cells(2, cell)
Next cell
End Sub
```

Appreciate any help / pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to vba, something like this can be done with formulas pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change to an incremented For .. Next and advance the increment step by 2.

```
Sub Loop_Sum()
    dim i as long, rng as range    
    Set rng = Range("A1:A6")
    For i= 1 to rng.cells.count step 2
        rng(i).offset(0, 1) = rng(i) + rng(i + 1)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah yes, the old eye-not-one paradigm. Good catch and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the Offset function:

```
Sub Loop_Sum()
Set rng = Range("A1:A6")
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Row Mod 2 = 0 Then 'Change 0 to 1 if it ends up on the worng row.
        cell.Offset(, 2) = cell + cell.Offset(1)
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

If you want a formula then put this in C2:

```
=If(mod(row(),2)=0,A2+A3,"")
```

And copy down.

Comment: How would you do it via formula?

Comment: Don't think you even need the [MOD function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MOD-function-D64C47F3-AAFD-4B2E-AE5D-C16EE3180576). The cells in column B are supposed to be merged; I'm assuming B1:B2 then B3:B4, etc. Just `=A1+A2` filled down should do it.

Comment: @Jeeped ah missed that.  You are correct, it should work as that simple.